# If $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $T(1, -1)^T=(0,1)^T, \space T(1,1)^T=(1,0)^T$, find $T(1, -7)^T.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $T(1, -1)^T=(0,1)^T, \space T(1,1)^T=(1,0)^T$, find $T(1, -7)^T.$

where $T$ is a linear transformation.
I assume I have to use the property of linear functions that $T(r_1+r_2)=T(r_1)+T(r_2)$, however I don't see where to use it. A hint would be appreciated- thanks!

Comment: The trasformation is completely determined by its value at two linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If (as written) you want to find $T(1,-7)^T$, then if you can write
   $$
    (1,-7)^T = \alpha (1,-1)^T + \beta (1,1)^T
   $$
   for some $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, then by linearity of $T$,
   $$
    T(1,-7)^T = T(\alpha(1,-1)^T + \beta(1,1)^T) = \alpha T(1,-1)^T + \beta T(1,1)^T = \ldots
   $$
2. If, instead, you want to find $(x,y)^T$ such that $T(x,y)^T = (1,-7)^T$, then if you can write
   $$
    (1,-7)^T = \alpha (1,0)^T + \beta (0,1)^T
   $$
   for some $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, then by linearity of $T$,
   $$
    (1,-7)^T = \alpha (1,0)^T + \beta (0,1)^T = \alpha T(1,1)^T + \beta T(1,-1)^T = T(\alpha(1,1)^T + \beta(1,-1)^T) = \ldots
   $$

Comment: Isn't this only if the question was asking $T(x,y)^T=(1,-7)^T?$

Comment: But that's what your question currently asks, as written...

Comment: I think the question is asking $T(1,-7)=(x,y)^T$

Comment: Sorry, yes. Your question, as you wrote it, asks to compute $T(1,-7)^T$.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan Edited to answer as well the question you seem to have wanted to ask instead of what you wrote.